# Is there a way to encrypt different parts of an mp4 with different keys?

Tags: encryption, video-streaming, mp4

And could this make it so that each corresponding part of the video can only be played once that key becomes available? Looking for a low resource way to "stream" a premade video. The client in this scenario would handle all the timing etc., but the encryption would keep anyone from looking ahead.

Comment: Yes all DRM systems support key rotation.